# how to get a value from a Sharepoint list with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint

i have the following code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var setTime = /*this should go the number*/
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * setTime;
        display = document.querySelector('#timer2');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

what i want is `var setTime` to get the value or retrieve from list with column named `testval` the datatype for `testval` is number
thanks all!

Comment: pls give us html code, where `testval` is

Comment: `testval` is a field in list it has a value of 15. i want `setTime` to be 15!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To communicate with SharePoint you need to use the JavaScript client object model as follows:

```
 var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
 var web = ctx.get_web();
 var listCollection = web.get_lists();
 var list = listCollection.getByTitle(NameOfYourList);
 var listItem = list.getItemById(TheItemID);
 context.load(listItem);

 context.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

and then

```
 function onQuerySucceeded() {
 var setTime =  listItem.get_item('testval');
 //continue your work
}

 function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
 alert('failed');
}
```

Remember to reference SP.js  script tag:

```
 <SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" Localizable="false" ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

Comment: Glad to help. you can accept answer if it works please.

Answer (score 2):

if it's a `td` elem like this `<td name="testval">15</td>`:

```
window.onload = function () {
   var testval = document.getElementsByName('testval')[0]; // if it's the first elem with this name
   //var testval = $('td[name=testval]'); // jquery
   var setTime = parseInt(testval.innerHTML); // 15
   var fiveMinutes = 60 * setTime;

   display = document.querySelector('#timer2');
   startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

jsFiddle for you - http://jsfiddle.net/y02os529/